# blank screen during booting

Tags: boot

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 along with windows7. After choosing Ubuntu from boot manager, many times i'm getting only a black screen. I'm not able to get gui or command line. Startup Ubuntu logo is not displayed. Only thing that can be done is turning off the power. Booting and restarting doesn't help either. Only if the laptop is kept idle for about an hour or two, ubuntu is booting properly. Only once I got the message saying /dev/tmp not found while booting. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

In Grub (boot manager) select the Ubuntu entry and press <kbd>e</kbd> now look for the words `quiet splash` navigate with your arrow keys to the place and replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset` now press <kbd>F10</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) to boot. See also this the answer at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076) question for a illustrated walktrough